# AG-Grid full row editing does not work if there are too many columns

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am using AG-grid community version JavaScript version and trying to edit rows using 'edit' action button as per the blog given [here](https://blog.ag-grid.com/full-row-editing-ag-grid-committing-changes-button-click/).
When the grid has more columns, edit feature stops working which we can test just by repeating columns in the colDef.
Code sandbox for the example is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-lederberg-sdlw2?from-embed)

I tried checking the event which should be triggered, but when the column numbers increases, the onRowEditing event stops firing.
It seems that when the grid is opened in a small screen(laptop), the edit stops working but working when opened in a larger screen.
Is there any limitation on how many columns we can add or edit before it stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default columns are virtualized. So you need to set a flag `suppressColumnVirtualisation: true` in grid options

Comment: Thanks mashi. It worked. I tried finding this but could not find anywhere